# Log URL that caused 404 in a DropWizard or Jetty application

Tags: java, jax-rs, jetty, dropwizard

We're running DropWizard and trying to drop in logging of the URLs that cause 404 responses to be thrown

We have a catchall exception mapper that receives a `NotFoundException`. Frustratingly that exception doesn't carry context of which URL caused it to be thrown.

Example application here: https://github.com/pauldambra/not.found.example

We're using an `ExceptionMapper`

```
public class NotFoundLogger implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {

    ExampleLogger logger = new ExampleLogger();

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(final NotFoundException exception) {
        logger.error(urlFrom(exception), exception);
        return Response.status(404).build();
    }

    private String urlFrom(final NotFoundException exception) {
        return "why is this not a property on the exception?!";
    }

    private class ExampleLogger {
        void error(final String notFoundUrl, final NotFoundException exception) {
            System.out.println("someone tried to load " + notFoundUrl);
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

If we look at the application logs when someone requests a URL that the application doesn't serve we see that the application can log that it is returning a 404 for a path but our custom logger has no access to the URL

```
someone tried to load why is this not a property on the exception?!
HTTP 404 Not Found
127.0.0.1 - - [08/May/2019:09:53:47 +0000] "GET /ping/pong HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Is an `ExceptionMapper` the wrong way to do this?

Comment: Can you access the `HttpServletRequest` that caused the exception during `toResponse()`?  per https://stackoverflow.com/q/17766072/775715

Comment: Or use `UriInfo` per https://stackoverflow.com/a/43610403/775715

Comment: Ooh that context mechanism looks promising! I hate that undiscoverable magic stuff though! (why isn't it just a method overload :D)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out there are two ways

one does use the exception mapper:

```
public class NotFoundLogger implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {

    // magically inject a thing
    // remember that magic is for evil wizards
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    private ExampleLogger logger = new ExampleLogger();

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(final NotFoundException exception) {
        final StringBuffer absolutePath = HttpUtils.getRequestURL(request);
        logger.error("exception mapper: " + absolutePath, exception);
        return Response.status(404).build();
    }
}
```

This works but isn't very discoverable.

You can also add a response filter

```
public class NotFoundLoggingFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    private ExampleLogger logger = new ExampleLogger();

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                       ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
        if (responseContext.getStatus() != 404) {
            return;
        }

        final URI absolutePath = requestContext.getUriInfo().getAbsolutePath();
        logger.error("filter: " + absolutePath, new NotFoundException());
    }
}
```

This doesn't require any magic so suits me but you can choose your poison.

Really the path should be on the `NotFoundException` - if I had more time I'd propose the code change to add it.